# Is there a secure way to use Redis with a Next.js app hosted on Vercel?

Tags: database, security, next.js, redis, vercel

I spent a couple of hours yesterday trying to find a way to use Redis with an app that runs on Vercel. According to [Redis docs on security](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/), it is not a good idea to expose a Redis instance directly to the internet:

> Redis is designed to be accessed by trusted clients inside trusted environments. This means that usually it is not a good idea to expose the Redis instance directly to the internet or, in general, to an environment where untrusted clients can directly access the Redis TCP port or UNIX socket.

I wanted to use Digital Ocean's trusted sources to restrict the incoming connections to those coming from my Vercel server but looks like that won't be possible because of Vercel's use of dynamic IP addresses. According to [Vercel docs](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-allowlist-deployment-ip-address):

> To ensure your Vercel deployment is able to access the external resource, you should allow connections from all IP addresses. Typically this can be achieved by entering an IP address of (0.0.0.0).

> While allowing connections from all IP addresses may be a concern, relying on IP allowlisting for security is generally ineffective and can lead to poor security practices.

> To properly secure your database, we recommend using a randomly generated password, stored as an environment variable, at least 32 characters in length, and to rotate this password on a regular basis.

I could rely on password authentication but that is, according to [Redis docs](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/#authentication), meant as another layer of redundancy rather than the main security measure. Am I missing something or is there no good way to use Redis with Vercel without compromising security?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to have Redis accessible over the internet and can't limit the IP addresses that are allowed to see it, a compromise might be to make sure you are using a Redis Access Control List.  This would allow you to configure a named user with a password that is limited to only running the command you need your application to run and potentially also to only accessing parts of the keyspace that you want your application to see/manipulate.  You'll need your Redis server version to be 6 or higher for this.

Another thing you could look at is whether Vercel publishes its IP ranges and also restrict access to those.  This won't guarantee that it's your application talking to Redis of course, but it'd limit it to at least Vercel hosted applications.  This would be an additional step on top of something like using an Access Control List user.

Redis Access Control Lists: https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/